# Ошибки python в pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Все встроенные в питоне функции начали подчеркиваться красным[image: введите сюда описание изображения], при  этом выдает такую ошибку [image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Попробовал менять кодировку проекта, ничего не помогает. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: формат файла то точно .py?

Comment: Учитывая, что тип файла Python File, смею предположить, что это файл py. Еще максимально интересно, кто поставил -1, наверно каждый день с такими вопросами сталкивается.

Answer (score 1):

Из-за ошибки с Non-UTF-8 было очевидно, что проблема с кодировкой, поэтому пытался играться с этой настройкой[image: введите сюда описание изображения], но какую бы кодировку для проекта не ставил, все равно одна и та же ошибка вылезала, при чем когда я удалил полностью весь код из файла и запустил, то все равно эта ошибка, то есть кода нет, а Non-UTF-8 есть.

Еще пробовал добавлять `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  в начало, также подставляя разные кодировки, ничего не помогало.
Еще, как вариант [как это использовать не понял](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/charset-encoding-problem-text-is-displayed-incorrectly.html).

В результате помогло открыть один из py файлов проекта(не работал ни один) с помощью Sublime text, далее File>Reopen with Encoding>UTF-8. Перезапустил pycharm и о чудо, заработало.